# YouTube wmode=opaque not working in IE9 (or any other IE)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to use wmode=opaque or something similar because I would like to place an image in front of the video (placeholder and arrow images as the videos will be in a slideshow).

However, I'm struggling to get this to work in any version of IE (even 9!).

I've also tried every variant of wmode - opaque, transparent, window and direct

Here is a link to the code...

http://jsfiddle.net/KtbYR/30/

Here is the actual code for preservation purposes...

```
/* HTML */
<div id="tabs2">
  <div>
     <img class='thumb' src='http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Arts_/Pictures/2003/12/04/explosions.jpg'>
   <iframe id="frame1" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" title="YouTube video player"type="text/html"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?e&wmode=opaque"></iframe>
</div>

<div>
   <img class='thumb' src='http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Arts_/Pictures/2003/12/04/explosions.jpg'>
   <iframe id="frame2" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" title="YouTube video player"type="text/html"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?wmode=opaque"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
/* CSS */
#tabs2 div {
    position: relative;
}

.thumb {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you testing whether this works in IE? I just checked and the image layers on top of the video properly

- [IE9](http://cl.ly/0o0d1d1S2h2N3r373647)
- [IE8](http://cl.ly/1o0P2P3d3Q072A2v1E3J)
- [IE7](http://cl.ly/1n2c3S1s313m0z143X2P)
- [IE6](http://cl.ly/3v2D3p3N0t1W3U0a3X1O)

Comment: Can you see the video though? When I play it, sound comes out but no video. It works on everything else. I'm using a VM with Windows 7 32-bit to test.

Comment: I can indeed see the video in all cases. My IE9 image is native in Windows 7 Pro 64bit. My IE8/7/6 images are in VMs and they all play as well.

Comment: That's really bizarre / annoying for me considering I've spent all day trying to solve this(!). just updating my Flash player now to see if it was that maybe. Do you have a BrowserStack account you can try on? Unfortunately my free plan has been used up!

Comment: That's really odd, I've connected to two remote machines and it works under both of them! Thanks

Comment: I don't have any accounts like that - glad you saw some success with the other machines. I wonder if there's a hardware acceleration option that is running amok in your VM.