# javascript to play youtube video isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

## html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">    body {    background-color: transparent;    color: white;    }    
</style>    
</head>
<body style="margin:0">    
<embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/6eK-W32IME0?fs=1&hl=en_US&enablejsapi=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="330" height="200"></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

The code I'm running to try to play the video is

```
var yt = document.getElementById("yt");
yt.playVideo();
```

The JS error I get is

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'playVideo'
```

But it seems like this is how everyone else does it. What's the deal?

** EDIT **

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3jgy/3)

** EDIT **

[The current JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3jgy/3) now works fine on a pc/mac, but not on an iPad.

Comment: It works ok for me http://jsfiddle.net/A3jgy/. In what browser are you testing?

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan http://jsfiddle.net/A3jgy/3/ is more like what I'm looking at. The embed works just fine, but the makeshift play button doesn't.

Comment: @Jackson I've updated my original answer with a working example using the `object` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add `&enablejsapi=1` to the querystring of the URL referencing the video in your `<embed>` object.

Also, try replacing your `<embed>` element with an `<object>` element. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3jgy/4/).

*A note about iOS/Mobile Webkit:*

Apparently, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9028877/1030243), Apple explicitly prohibits automated control of embedded media in Safari or other Mobile Webkit browsers, requiring the iOS user to interact directly with the video object to initiate playback. This goes for `object` and `embed` elements, as well as HTML5 `video` and `audio` elements.

Comment: Works great on a computer, but not on the iPad for some reason. It has to work there so I'm perplexed atm.

Comment: Well, that's because iOS devices don't support Flash. Period. If you use an iframe embed the video on your page, YouTube will intelligently detect the viewers' devices and serve the appropriate version of the video for each one. Then, however, you'll lose the script control you're trying to implement. Long story short: you'll need to detect Flash capability on your page and generate an `object` or `video` tag based on the result of that test.

Comment: I should point out that the video playing actually DOES work on the ipad (youtube is doing something fancy here). It's just that the `playVideo` function is kind of busted in the ipad.

Comment: Apparently, according to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9028877/1030243), Apple explicitly prohibits automated control of embedded media in Safari, requiring the iOS user to interact directly with the video object to initiate playback.

Comment: Aaron, maybe you should move your last Comment to the Answer. It's an important piece of info. Damn Apple, not even in Chrome we can initiate the playback externally.

Comment: Good thinking. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

you're not loading the JS api try this:

```
<embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/6eK-W32IME0?fs=1&hl=en_US&enablejsapi=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="330" height="200"></embed>
```

to learn more about youtubes JS api check out https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: hmm. Still the same thing. (new code added to my original example)