# Autoplaying and manual playing youtube video on iphone not working by using javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

```
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

      players = new YT.Player('player1', {
      height: '640',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'E_fXGeg_UA4',
     events: 
     {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
       }
    });

   function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  } 
  }
```

`players.playVideo();` also not working.

Comment: It's not possible to autoplay videos on iOS devices. Period.

Comment: but playVIdeo() also not working.

Comment: `playVideo()` is another means of autoplaying, and the fact that it doesn't work is expected. This comes up frequently on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Byoutube-api%5D+autoplay

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem involving Youtube player on iOS app using native viewer, in which case the UIWebView can be [coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050215/1271086) into autoplaying videos using `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property.

```
self.webViewer.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

and you're good to go. Both `player.playVideo()` and `event.target.playVideo()` works nicely. As of iOS 6.1, there is no way to coax Safari into enabling the autoplay/`playVideo()` method