# youtube iframe API does not work on ipad and iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I was trying to recreate the multiple iframes example [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948403/youtube-api-target-multiple-existing-iframes) for a slideshow. It works flawlessly in all browsers, including desktop safari, except on iphone and ipad.

http://codepen.io/lakshminp/pen/mepIB

Js:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var players = {}

var YT_ready = (function() {
    var onReady_funcs = [],
        api_isReady = false;
    return function(func, b_before) {
        if (func === true) {
            api_isReady = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < onReady_funcs.length; i++) {
                // Removes the first func from the array, and execute func                                                                                                                     
                onReady_funcs.shift()();
            }
    }
        else if (typeof func == "function") {
            if (api_isReady) func();
            else onReady_funcs[b_before ? "unshift" : "push"](func);
        }
    }
})();


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    YT_ready(true);
  });
}

YT_ready(function() {
        var identifier = "v9d09JLBVRc";
            players[identifier] = new YT.Player(identifier, {
                events: {
                  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    "onStateChange": createYTEvent(identifier)
                }
            });
});

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// Returns a function to enable multiple events                                                                                                                                                
function createYTEvent(identifier) {
    var player = players[identifier]; // Get cached player instance                                                                                                                            
    return function (event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="yt-container">
  <iframe width="640" height="480" id="v9d09JLBVRc" class="media-youtube-player" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/v9d09JLBVRc?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

> functions and parameters such as autoplay, playVideo(), loadVideoById() won't work in all mobile environments

and in your `YTReady` function, you load dynamically a video and for the moment that's not possible on iOS.

You can also try the [YouTubeDemoPage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) and try to load another id and you will see that it can't be done.

You should also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219959/2806832).