# YouTube Javascript API not working as expected on iPad iOS8

Tags: javascript, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube Javascript API to embed a YouTube video in my webapp and it works perfectly everywhere (including IE8!), but not on my iPad in Safari.

The code:

```
$(function() {
    var scriptTag = $('<script></script');
    scriptTag.attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api');
    $('body').append(scriptTag);
});

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: videoHeight,
        width: videoWidth,
        videoId: videoId,
        suggestedQuality: "hd720",
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert('change:' + event.data);
}
```

The setup works fine, the onPlayerReady event fires, but the video doesn't start playing.  onPlayerStateChange fires twice, once with a -1 (unstarted) and then a 3 (buffering), but nothing plays and no controls appear.

I've tried this with different videos and I get the same result.

Here's a live example:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2497368/yt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out iOS don't allow you to autoplay videos, which is the issue here.

[YouTube API not working in iOS (iPhone/iPad) but working fine in Desktop browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513620/youtube-api-not-working-in-ios-iphone-ipad-but-working-fine-in-desktop-browser)