# how to detect error state for "if playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device" on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I have embedded the youtube in my iOS application using iFrame. it works fine but the only exception it is throwing is sometimes while loading the video it displays the error message."if playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device", and the video don't gets loaded until I restart the controller, 
Is there any kind of error handler in to handle this state.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902844/how-to-fix-if-playback-doesnt-begin-shortly-try-restarting-your-device-using

Comment: I have handled the auto play situation already but this problem is still there, and this behaviour is random